# IntelliJ and PyCharm will not display code return, just code 0

Tags: display, intellij-idea, pycharm

When running a simple program - as simple as:

```python
print("hello world")
```

All I'm getting from IntelliJ and PyCharm now is the standard:

> process finished with exit code 0

Nothing else happens. This was working fine yesterday, now suddenly I can't get anything to run. All I did was remove some older Python installations I had (2.7 and 3.5 for training purposes) After the problem began I have uninstalled everything and re-installed everything - three times, even reverted back to older versions. Still nothing.

Anyone out there that can help me before I break my keyboard beating my head against it?

I'm running Windows 10, but the OS doesn't seem to have anything to do with it, as nothing on the OS has changed.  The OS will be updated tonight, however, so maybe we'll see for sure.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User! We are always glad to help, but you apparently have two Super User accounts: [this one](https://superuser.com/users/723450/jakep) and [this one](https://superuser.com/users/723458/jake). Please take the time to utilize the following Help Center tutorial and ask the Super User staff to merge your accounts: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem as well (on Windows 10).

For me the issue was solved by removing the `.idea` folder and opening the project as a new project in PyCharm.